# AWS Lambda package-deployed functions require() of a relative path, not found

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have a zip file containing the following structure (this is the root of the archive, not nested in a top-level folder, which I understand is a common cause of errors for aws-s3-lambda deployments):

```
- support/
    - shared.js
- one.js
- two.js
```

and then in one.js and two.js:

```
var shared = require("./support/shared");

// ...
```

When I run this code locally, it works.  I use the aws-sdk to upload the zip file to AWS-S3 and then use aws.lambda.createFunction() to create a function with that name and handler and everything.  The created function DOES show up in my Lambda dashboard, but when I test it, I get `"Cannot find module './support/shared'"`.  I have also tried `var shared = require("./support/shared.js");` and that gives `"Cannot find module './support/shared.js'"`.

This is for runtime `node6.10`.  The filename cases are correct for case-sensitive lambda.

Shouldn't this work??  What's the gotcha?

Is there a way to verify the file structure that Lambda is working in to show that the additional `./support/shared.js` file actually made it to the working directory or whatever it uses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gotcha is that the zip file created on a windows machine has the wrong chmod permissions set in it for when AWS unpacks it.  The files are there, but inaccessible but node just gives a generic warning about not found instead of that the folder access is denied.